# Best Practice Multi Country with Bilingual Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, multicurrency

Wondering how to attain this setup for magento?

I have these countries

- Oman
- Qatar
- UAE
- Saudi Arabia
- Jordan

But Language should only be English and Arabic for all. In this case, products should only be English and Arabic. What's in my mind is to create 2 views for each country but this is a lot of work. Is there any easier way wherein I just need to create only 2 views but all countries will share these 2 views? Please see image.

[image: See Diagram]

Comment: Create store view for each language. Then set allowed countries for default configuration scop

Comment: What I am avoiding is multiple product/catalog description in Arabic. If you look at the diagram, those countries will have 2 languages and intended to lessen the job of data encoder. All countries have 2 different views RTL (arabic) and LTR (english). In this case, encoders should only create 2 descriptions for each products.

Comment: Also, I want to keep the dropdown menu for country selection.